# jQuery content separation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the follow structure:

```
<div class="cardapio-content">
    <h5>Tittle of tab 1</h5>
    <p>Content of tab 1</p>
    <h5>Tittle of tab 2</h5>
    <p>Content of tab 2</p>
    <h5>Tittle of tab 3</h5>
    <p>Content of tab 3</p>
</div>
```

And want to get each `h5` and add to another div `<div class="cardapio-menu">`, associating the `p` content below the `h5` to each tab.

I have tried with `each` but don't know how to get the `p` relative to the `h5` index..

```
jQuery('.cardapio-content h5').each(function(k, v) {
    alert(jQuery('.cardapio-content')[k].html());
})
```

Thanks.

Comment: please show the expected output too - I can't figure it out from your text description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `.next()`:

```
jQuery('.cardapio-content h5').each(function(){
    var h5 = $(this);
    var p = $(this).next();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/next

Comment: You can do `.next('p')` to make sure it's a `<p>`.

Comment: Learn something new everyday :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery's `.eq` to get the element you want.

```
jQuery('.cardapio-content h5').each(function(k, v) {
    alert(jQuery('.cardapio-content p').eq(k).html());
})
```

Answer (score 1):

## [DEMO jsBin](http://jsbin.com/icukel/edit#javascript,html,live)

Just used in an `each` function the [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [.andSelf()](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) selectors, wrapping them together:

```
$('.cardapio-content h5').each(function(){
  $(this).next('p').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="cardapio-menu" />');
});
```